# SSL HTTPS Padlock Visible In IE, Firefox, Safari, but Not In Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, cross-browser, browser

I have a webpage (php form using yii framework) secured by ssl that shows an SSL padlock with a yellow alert in Google Chrome.  I have not been able to identify the problem and am stumped.  It seems to be related to my page and is specific to Google Chrome (other browsers work fine).

Troubleshooting so far:

**Eliminated Cache as the Cause**

- Completely cleared my Google Chrome cache to ensure that previously loaded components were not causing the problem.
- Tested the page on a separate machine to confirm that the alert is visible on a different system not related to my machine.  Alert on page was generated on separate system.

**Scoped the Problem to an Element on My Page**

- Setup a simple page under the same domain, successfully generated the padlock.
- Tested failing page at https://www.whynopadlock.com/check.php and the script indicates that all components are called securely.  No alerts generated.

**Scoped the Problem To Google Chrome**

- Tested in Internet Explorer - No alerts
- Tested in Safari - No Alerts
- Tested in Firefox - No Alerts

Does anybody know of a page element that will cause an alert (broken padlock) in Google Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer, Safari, or Firefox?

Comment: Does the alert not come with a message?

Comment: Yes, sorry Joachim... It does indicate that something on the page is not secure.  However, whatever the element on the page is, it is not detected by the other browsers or the tool at www.whynopadlock.com.